# PHP Authentication error using X-SmartToken

Tags: php, api, authentication

Ok so the instructions to connect to this API are:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/jobs?limit=10&offset=0" -H "accept: application/json" -H "X-SmartToken: xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

So my PHP looks like the below but I am getting this **[message] => Authentication data missing**

```
$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$url = "https://api.xxxxxxx.com/jobs?limit=10&offset=0";

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$ch = curl_init($url);
$authorization = "Authorization: X-SmartToken ".$token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r(json_decode($result));
exit;
```

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$authorization = "X-SmartToken: ".$token;
```

The : was missing and the Authorization needed to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not prepend `Authorization:` to the HTTP header:

```
$authorization = "X-SmartToken: " . $token;
```

Comment: Check @StephenDance response. ':' was missing. Edited my answer accordingly.